# Using NSPredicate to find an object with a key starting with an @

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have this JSON object that I load into an NSDictionary:

```
media =     {
       photos =         {
           photo =             (
                               {
                   "$t" = "http://some url";
                   "@id" = 1;
                   "@size" = x;
               },
                               {
                   "$t" = "http://another url";
                   "@id" = 1;
                   "@size" = fpm;
               },
                               {
              );
       };
};
```

I am trying to search the photos array and return just the photo with the @size attribute = x.

I thought this would work but it is returning zero objects:

```
 NSObject *photo = [[photos valueForKeyPath:@"media.photos.photo"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == x",@"@size"]];
```

I have tried putting single quotes around the 'x' but that fails too.  I think it is the @ sign in the attribute name itself that is causing the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

The key starting with the @ seems to be the problem.  If I try to use NSPredicate to search the array it throws a "NSUnknownKeyException... class is not key value compliant" error.

I am able to search with nested for loops like this:

> ```
> for (id photo in photos)
>  {
>      for (id key in photo) 
>      {
>          id value = [photo objectForKey:key];
>
>          if ([key isEqualToString:@"@size"] && [value isEqualToString:@"x"])
>          {
>            stringXLargePhotoUrl = [photo valueForKey:@"$t"];
>            break;
>           }
>       }
>       if (stringXLargePhotoUrl != Nil)
>          break;
>    }
> ```

But that is pretty clunky.  I would rather use the NSPredicate if possible.  I don't control the JSON object so I can't just change key to not start with an @.

Answer (score 0):

This article is very good and could be helpful http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

> %@ is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string,
>   number, or date.
>
> %K is a var arg substitution for a key path.

Change

```
 ... [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == x",@"@size"]];
```

to

```
 ... [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == x",@"@size"]];
```

( `@` to `K` ).

Comment: Thanks but I still have my problem.  It is the @ symbol in the property.  It is being seen as a "Collections Operator".  My app crashes when I use your code suggestion with the error "NSUnknownKeyException... class is not key value compliant".  I assume that means I am not allowed to use the @ symbol in my property.  Unfortunately I don't control the JSON object and I can't find a way to escape the @ symbol.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dave: Have you tried using a backslash as the escape character e.g. `"\@size"`?

Comment: "\@size" raises "unknown escape sequence" warning.  Running the code with the warning returns nothing found.  Thanks though.

Comment: you could remove the @ symbols from your json string before serializing it to the NSDictionary if nothing else works.